# How to handle - SESN0008E A user has attempted to access a session owned by user - on WebSphere

Tags: jsf, error-handling, websphere, forms-authentication

I'm working on my JSF application using a Form Auth.

I got myself stuck cause of SESN0008E error handling. I understand that error occures when logged user want to authenticate as another user, while logged user session still exists.

For now its possible to check if user is logged in when he enters login page. If he is authenticated, I simply redirect him to homepage.

However error can be still reproduced - just open the login page in two tabs and login into different accounts.

For login I'm using simple login.xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template/login/layout.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">

            <p:outputLabel value="#{loginHandler.alreadyLoggedRedirect()}"></p:outputLabel>

            <form action="j_security_check" method="post">
                <p:panelGrid id="loginContentPanel" columns="2">
                    <p:outputLabel for="j_username" value="Username" />
                    <p:inputText id="j_username" />
                    <p:outputLabel for="j_password" value="Password" />
                    <p:password id="j_password"></p:password>
                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <div id="loginButtonCenter">
                            <h:commandButton id="loginButton"
                                styleClass="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"
                                value="Login" />
                        </div>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:panelGrid>
            </form>

        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

loginHandler.alreadyLoggedRedirect() handles redirect when user is already logged in.

And here is part of web.xml:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>User Auth</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login.xhtml?s=err</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>User Auth</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
```

**I wonder if I can handle this exception and logout current user automatically?**

I simply want to logout current user on new user login attempt.

Comment: Try to invalidate session in your login page (login.xhtml). In that way you should always get fresh session on login.

Comment: Have you found solution to this?